# DataFrame.replace by nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge Dataframe, where a lot of entries needs to be changed. So, I've created a translation dict, which has the following structure:

```
{'Data.Bar Layer': {'1': 0,
  '1.E': 21,
  '2': 13,
  '2.E': 22,
  '3': 14,
  '3.E': 24,
  '4': 15,
  '4.E': 23,
  'B': 16,
  'CL1': 1,
  'CL2': 2,
  'CL2a': 6,
  'CL3': 3,
  'CL3a': 4,
  'CL4': 5,
  'E': 18,
  'L1': 7,
  'L2': 8,
  'L2a': 12,
  'L3': 9,
  'L3a': 10,
  'L4': 11,
  'T': 17,
  'T&B': 19,
  'T+B': 20},
 'Data.Bar Type': {'N': 0, 'R': 1},
 'Data.Defined No. Bars': {'No': 0, 'Yes': 1},
 'Data.Design Option': {'-1': 0, 'Main Model': 1},...}
```

[screenshot of the dictionaries print representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DowYs.png)

The first key corresponds to the dataframe column and the second key to the value that needs to be changed, e.g. in column `Data.Bar Layer` all `'1'` should be 0. [This is how the documentation of pandas.dataframe.replace states the dictionary to look like](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
However, same values have to be exchanged multiple times, which (I guess) leads to the error:

> Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values

[Here is a snippet of the Dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Vyi.png) Is there any work around to avoid this error? I tried some approaches with apply and map, but they didn't work, unfortunately.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more pythonic way, but this code works for me;

```
for col in your_dict.keys():
    df[col].replace(your_dict[col], inplace=True)
```